# Django: post form and post list on the same page

Tags: python, html, django

I make a site with multiple users, making posts with images and ability to add/remove friends.
So it's easy to make two different pages for post list and creating a new one. But of course it looks better when you can read posts and make new at the same place.

As I understand (learn django for less than a month), I can't connect 2 views to the same url, so the most logical way I see is to join 2 views in one, I also tried to play with template inheriting to render post form by including template, but actually it doesn't work.

Below you can see my views, Post model, and templates. Thank you for attention.

views.py:

```
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin
from . import models
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class PostList(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ('user',)

class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
    fields = ('post_message', 'post_image')
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ('user',)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit = False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

models.py:

```
import misaka

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'posts')
    posted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    post_message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable = False)
    post_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'postpics', blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_message

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.message_html = misaka.html(self.post_message)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:all')

    class Meta:

        ordering = ['-posted_at']
        unique_together = ['user', 'post_message']
```

urls.py:

```
app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name = 'all'),
    path('new/', views.CreatePost.as_view(), name = 'create'),
]
```

post_form.html (template, that allows to make a new post, which will be seen in post_list.html):

```
{% extends 'posts/post_base.html'%}
{% block post_content %}
<div class="post-form">
  <form action="{% url 'posts:create' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ form.post_message }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.post_image }}</p>
    <input id='post-submit' type="submit" value="Post">
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

post_list.html:

```
{% extends 'posts/post_base.html'%}
{% block post_content %}
<div class="post-container">
  {% for post in post_list %}
  <div class="current-post-container">
    {% include 'posts/_post.html'%}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

_post.html(pages, which render by Misaka):

```
<div class="post-info">
  <h5 id='post-owner' >{{post.user.first_name}} {{post.user.last_name}}</h5>
  <h6>{{ post.posted_at }}</h6>
  <p>{{ post.message_html|safe }}</p>
  <div>
    <img class='post-image'  src="/media/{{ post.post_image }}" alt="">
    <div>
      {% if user.is_authenticated and post.user == user and not hide_delete %}
      <a href="{% url 'posts:delete' pk=post.pk %}" title = 'delete'>Delete</a>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

post_base.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content%}
        {% block prepost %}{% endblock %}
        {% block post_content %}{% endblock %}
        {% block post_post %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT:**
Task was solved. I added two template_name strings to both of my views, so now they look like:

CreatePost in views.py:

```
class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
    fields = ('post_message', 'post_image')
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ('user',)
    template_name = 'posts/post_list.html'
    template_name = 'posts/post_form.html'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit = False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

PostList in views.py:

```
class PostList(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ('user',)
    template_name = 'posts/post_list.html'
    template_name = 'posts/post_form.html'
```

Comment: Please read this article, here an example how to create dynamic content on the page using django-forms and ajax https://realpython.com/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/

Comment: Regarding the EDIT: why do you set `template_name` twice? They will just have the second of both values afaik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the post_create_form on the same page as post_list_view there is no need to make a separate view for post creation but You need to make ones for editing and deleting.
You can give all of these views the same HTML page with different URLs.
Using `template_name = 'example/example.html'` ,in Class_Based_Views.
I hope I understand your problem if not clarify more why you can't join two views in one.

Comment: I've tried so many ways to join these PostList and CreatePost views in one, but it doesn't work in any case I did. Anyway I see only creating form or only list of posts.
I thought about making a new class, which will contain all code from these two classes and will inherit them both, but it doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

```
def posts(request):
posts = Post.objects.all()

form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
       ...

context={
    'posts'         : page_obj,
    'create_or_update_post_form' : form,

}
return  render(request, 'post/posts.html',context)
```

Do you struggle to do this in Class-based-view?

Comment: I've already solved this trouble using your previous answer, now I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily with django class based views.

- Create views as

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class ModelCreate(CreateView):
    model = ModelName
    fields = ['field1', 'field2']
    template_name = 'same_page.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('list_view')


class ModelList(CreateView, ListView):
    model = ModelName
    fields = ['field1', 'field2']
    paginate_by = 5
    template_name = 'same_page.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    # If form post redirect to ModelCreate View
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return ModelCreate.as_view()(request)
```

- app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from app import views

path('list', views.ModelList.as_view(), name='list_view'),
path('add', views.ModelCreate.as_view(), name='add_view'),
```

- Finally in templates/same_page.html

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-5">
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{form.as_p}}
         <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Submit</button>                              
       </form>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-5">
    {% if object_list %}
       {% for object in object_list %}
         <p>{{object.field1}}</p>
         <p>{{object.field2}}</p>
       {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
   </div>
</div>
```

Hope, this helps.